# find the number of ways to reach the nth stair

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, dynamic-programming

I have to find the number of ways to reach the $n$th stair step (where $n=20$) by taking at most 5 steps at a time, with the restriction that the $5$th, $10$th, and $15$th should not be accessed.

**Working**

I know how to find the number of way to reach the $n$th step given at most $k$ steps for this. If $n=20$ and $k=5$, the total number of ways are $400096$, but I don't know how to count if exceptions are given, like the $5$th, $10$th, and $15$th steps should not be accessed.

Comment: It could be framed a bit more clearly if we understood whether "5th 10th 15th" stair steps need to be accessed, i.e. could these not be accessed at all?  In particular is it allowed to go to the 20th step directly, without taking any intermediate steps?  I suspect that the clause "by taking at most 5 steps at a time" was originally intended to apply to all stages, not merely to accessing the "5th 10th 15th" steps (or not).

Comment: you can take atmost 5 steps at a time and the pattern should be such that the 5th 10th and 15th stair is not visited

Comment: @DANKUPLOADER " *I know ... the total number of ways are 400096* " How did you get this number?

Comment: I suspect you were intended to model this as a probability transition matrix, with states corresponding to steps $1$ to $20$, making steps $5,10,15$ and $20$ be *absorbing states*.  Is this terminology familiar to you?

Comment: Depending on what you expect to happen if a "turn" randomly takes one *past* the $20$th step, you might need to add another absorbing state that corresponds to whatever lies beyond the $20$th step.

Answer (score 3):

First a question: If we ignore the "must not touch 5th, 10th, 15th steps" constraint, you seem to have a way to calculate $f(n=20,k=5) = 400096$.  How do you do that?  One can obviously write a simple recurrence (dynamic program, loop) - is that how you do it?  Or do you have some other way?

Anyway, the answer: assuming you can calculate $f(n,k)$ for other values, then the problem with the constraint can simply be handled by inclusion exclusion.  Let $P_5, P_{10}, P_{15}$ be the set of paths that touch each of the name restricted step (and satisfying $n=20, k=5$), then your answer is

$$f(20,5) - |P_5| - |P_{10}| - |P_{15}| + |P_5 \cap P_{10}| + |P_5 \cap P_{15}| + |P_{10} \cap P_{15}| - |P_5 \cap P_{10} \cap P_{15}| $$

Calculating each of the terms is easy.  E.g.

- $|P_5| = f(5,5) \times f(15,5)$ because you must first reach the 5th step (there being $f(5,5)$ ways to do so), then continue for 15 more ($f(15,5)$ ways to do so);
- $|P_{10}| = f(10,5) \times f(10,5)$ because you must first reach the 10th step, then continue for 10 more;
- $|P_5 \cap P_{10}| = f(5,5)\times f(5,5)\times f(10,5)$;
- $|P_5 \cap P_{10} \cap P_{15}| = f(5,5) \times f(5,5)\times f(5,5)\times f(5,5)$ etc.
- In each case, by specifying which (forbidden) step(s) you must touch, you have broken up the 20-step path into segments, and you can calculate $f(n',k)$ for each segment of length $n'$ and just multiply them all together.

Comment: @DANKUPLOADER - see the edits.  hope they answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem can be set up recursively.

Let $A=\{n : $ we must avoid stair $n \}$.

Let $b_n$ be the number of ways to reach stair $n$.

You will need to find initial conditions for $b_0$ through $b_4$. (Note: $b_0 = 1$. There is $1$ way to be at the foot of the stairs.)

Then our recursion will be, for $n\ge 5$: $$b_n = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & {\rm if\:} n\in A\\b_{n-1}+b_{n-2}+b_{n-3}+b_{n-4}+b_{n-5}& \rm otherwise\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: +1 nice simple recursion!  simpler and better than using inclusion-exclusion as in my answer.

Comment: well n is 20 and is too large for it to be solved recursively can you suggest a dynamic or recursive code

Comment: @DANK UPLOADER I'm not sure what you mean that it is 'too large to be solved recursively'.  I think it would take about 5 minutes to run the recursion out to 20 (using say a handheld calculator for some of the additions of larger values). I'd be curious to know how you solved the problem without restricted steps to get $400096$ ways to get to the 20th step. Running the restricted recursion really shouldn't be any harder (and in fact the numbers are smaller because of the steps with $b_n=0$).

Comment: I did make a recursive program but the problem is it's given answer with the conditions you said as 39648 which i know isn't correct the answer for n=20 and k=5 i got it from that code only
`#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int totalWays(int n, int m)
{
 // base case: invalid input
 if (n < 0||n==5||n==10||n==15)
  return 0;

 // base case: 1 way (with no steps)
 if (n == 0)
  return 1;

 int count = 0;
 for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++)

  count += totalWays(n - i, m);

 return count;
}
int main(void)
{
 int n = 20, m = 5;
 cout<<totalWays(n, m);
 return 0;
}`

Comment: mathematician finally found the staircase to heaven having 20 stairs. He is standing on 0th level and wants to reach the 20th level of staircase. But there are 3 stairs on which if he steps then he will go to hell numbered 5th 10th and 15th and thus would not be able to reach heaven. He can climb maximum of 5 stairs in a single jump. As our society is concerned about our member, tell us the probability that he will go to heaven and not hell. (round off 5th decimal place)
this is the actual question can you help now ?

Comment: Why do you think $39648$ is incorrect?  I think it is ok.  (But maybe I'm mistaken.)

Comment: The probabilistic question is different, and you should have asked that separately.  :)  Anyway, the probabilistic question is actually unanswerable until we specify the probabilistic model.  E.g. one perfect valid model would be the guy takes a random move of $1$ to $5$ steps, uniform, each time, and he reaches heaven if he goes to $20$ _or beyond_ (or equivalently, he adjusts the last move so he never exceeds $20$).  For such a model, what you're asking in terms of no. of ways is irrelevant, because two different ways of different number of moves would not be equi-probable.

Comment: My [implementation](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/31HBViHaVEfB0ACITWO5kkB8IBuODGO5/IBiRgZcaflFCnkKmXkKhnp6flwKQJCkV1BanKGRFK1rqqenaxirV1yaqwmRiQZygdoMFDLTFBz1MvOSc0pTUu0V8rhS81K4Cooy80qAakzAuv7/BwA) gives $b_{20}=39648$ as claimed. Note that manually evaluating more base cases is unnecesary since $b_k=0$ for $k<0$.